# ¿Por qué Label LineBreakMode="WordWrap" en FlexLayout no funciona y en StackLayout sí?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xaml

Al diseñar UI del usuario móvil me encuentro el problema, que un label tiene bastante texto, entonces intento que ocupa varias líneas, no funciona en FlexLayout. En cambio antes en StackLayout sí que me funciona LineBreakMode="WordWrap".

¿Hay alguna posiblidad de que funciona bien en FlexLayout el Label?

```
<StackLayout Grid.Column="1">
  <Entry Text="{Binding SceneTitle}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="0,5,0,5" />
  <Label Text="{Binding SelectActionTypeForTheScene, FallbackValue='Select the action to be executed:'}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Style="{StaticResource LabelBrown}" />
</StackLayout>
```

Lo anterior funciona, en cambio siguiente código no:

```
<FlexLayout Grid.Column="1" Direction="Row">
  <Entry Text="{Binding SceneTitle}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="0,5,0,5" />
  <Label Text="{Binding SelectActionTypeForTheScene, FallbackValue='Select the action to be executed:'}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Style="{StaticResource LabelBrown}" />
</FlexLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tu problema está al definir el esquema de tu UI:

Espero no equivocarme, yo utilizo el siguiente código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
             x:Class="MyApp.MainPage">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" >
            <Entry Text="{Binding SceneTitle}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="0,5,0,5" />
            <Label Text="{Binding SelectActionTypeForTheScene, FallbackValue='Select the action to be executed in the screen to see how its working here only here:'}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Style="{StaticResource LabelBrown}" />
        </StackLayout>

        <FlexLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Direction="Row">
            <Entry Text="{Binding SceneTitle}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="0,5,0,5" />
            <Label Text="{Binding SelectActionTypeForTheScene, FallbackValue='Select the action to be executed in the screen to see how its working here only here:'}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Style="{StaticResource LabelBrown}" />
        </FlexLayout>

    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Y este es mi resultado:

[image: Captura de emulador]

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias. Parece que funciona.